# For Kivy in Python, I cannot get color on a canvas layout when I form multiple widgets

Tags: python, canvas, binding, widget, kivy

So I used a 'for loop' to create multiple rectangular widgets (e.g. `box`) in a row where I plan to put addition stuff inside.  I thought it would be nice for those widget to be spaced and have color in the background.  I research for about a week on everything (including 'binding'), but I still do not have the results I want.
Essentially, all the widgets (e.g.`box`) is in a function called `def test(self):` and called it up in the `__init__` to create the rows of widgets.  I use the `with self.canvas.before` and the `self.rec = Rectangle(size=box.size, pos=box.pos)` and the `def redraw(self,*args):` technique...but all I get is small box in the bottom left corner.

Please take a look and tell me what I am missing.  I will simplify the code:

````
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color 
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle

class TestWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.test()
        self.redraw

    def test(self):
        for i in range(3):
            box = BoxLayout(size_hint=(None,None), size=(300,50), pos=self.pos)
            with box.canvas.before:
                Color(1,0,0,0.5)
                self.rec = Rectangle(size=box.size, pos=box.pos)
                self.bind(size=self.redraw,pos=self.redraw)

            bt = Button(text='world')
            box.add_widget(bt)
            self.ids.stack.add_widget(box)

    def redraw(self, *args):
        self.rec.size = self.rec.size
        self.rec.pos = self.rec.pos

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return TestWindow()

if __name__=='__main__':
    TestApp().run()```

```The kv file is:
<TestWindow>:
    StackLayout:
        id:stack
        padding:10
        spacing:10```

[the output...][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyElC.jpg
````

Comment: During the `__init__()` of any `Widget`, the `size` will always be (100, 100) and the `pos` will always be `(0,0)`. It is not until the `Widget` is displayed that the `size` and `pos` are updated. So all your `Rectangles` are at (0,0) with size (100,100). What happens if you resize the window?

Comment: Nothing happens when the window resizes...it remains at pos(0,0) and size(100,100).

Comment: Can't tell what is going on without a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this code works now, when my previous attempts failed.  Maybe because I used a dictionary for my boxlayout (the same as what John Anderson, suggested).  Anyways, it looks like it is working great now...there might be some bugs later that I overlooked:

````
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle

class Test2Window(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        box = {}
        for i in range(5):
            box[i] = BoxLayout(size_hint=(None,None),size=(200,80),padding=5, spacing=5)
            box[i].bind(pos=self.redraw)

            bt = Button(text='Hello World')
            box[i].add_widget(bt)
            self.ids.stack.add_widget(box[i])

    def redraw(self,inst_box,*args):
        inst_box.canvas.before.clear()
        colr = Color(1,0,0,0.5)
        rec = Rectangle(size=inst_box.size, pos=inst_box.pos)

        inst_box.canvas.before.add(colr)
        inst_box.canvas.before.add(rec)

class Test2App(App):
    def build(self):

        return Test2Window()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Test2App().run()```

The KV file:
```<Test2Window>:
    StackLayout:
        id:stack
        padding:10
        spacing:10```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with your code. The first I mentioned in my previous comment (The `pos` and `size` attributes are not yet set in the `__init__()` method). And the second is that your `redraw()` method is not actually doing anything (setting a variable to its own value does nothing).

So here is a modified version of your code that make use of `Clock.schedule_once()` to overcome the first problem. And the second problem is handled by keeping a dictionary of the `Rectangles`, keyed on the corresponding `BoxLayout`, and adjusting each `Rectangle` using the `size` and `pos` of its `BoxLayout`:

```
from functools import partial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle


class TestWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.recs = {}
        Clock.schedule_once(self.test)

    def test(self, *args):
        for i in range(3):
            box = BoxLayout(size_hint=(None,None), size=(300,50))
            with box.canvas.before:
                Color(1,0,0,0.5)
                self.recs[box] = Rectangle(size=box.size, pos=box.pos)
                redraw_box = partial(self.redraw, box)
                self.bind(size=redraw_box,pos=redraw_box)

            bt = Button(text='world')
            box.add_widget(bt)
            self.ids.stack.add_widget(box)
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.redraw, box, None))

    def redraw(self, box, window_size, *args):
        self.recs[box].size = box.size
        self.recs[box].pos = box.pos


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return TestWindow()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Builder.load_string('''
<TestWindow>:
    StackLayout:
        id:stack
        padding:10
        spacing:10
    ''')
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Wow, you figured it out.  Thanks.  I spend much time trying the solve the window resizing issue.  Now, I just have study and understand your code...I guess I am still a newbie :)